# My Flutter App is Crashing on several devices after launching on playstore

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, apk

I have launched an app on play store but it is crashing on several devices & I am not able test my app on every devices.
i have crashlytics report

**Crashlytics Report
Stack Trace**

I am getting this error in android version 6

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ld/e/c/a/c;
 at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java)
       at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java)
       at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java)
       at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
       at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
       at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6(GrpcCallProvider.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6$GrpcCallProvider(GrpcCallProvider.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$GrpcCallProvider$SCD5iiibQ8l4haiO8ofSfE0wIJg.call(-.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzv.run(zzv.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run(-.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "d.e.c.a.c" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.bn.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.gu.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.hi.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.kn.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.mr.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.ta.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.te.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.bn.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.en.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.gu.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.hi.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.kn.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.mr.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.ta.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.te.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.scaptor.bkdschool-1/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java)
       at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java)
       at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java)
       at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
       at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
       at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6(GrpcCallProvider.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6$GrpcCallProvider(GrpcCallProvider.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$GrpcCallProvider$SCD5iiibQ8l4haiO8ofSfE0wIJg.call(-.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzv.run(zzv.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run(-.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Logs**

```
Crashlytics - Custom logs
Application: com.myapp.name
Platform: android
Version: 1.0.9 (9)
Issue: 249cf5c99a9e11ad407fca359f935c56
Session: 60FE32E9034000012DDEB2B2FD120ABC_DNE_0_v2
Date: Mon Jul 26 2021 09:28:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

0 | Mon Jul 26 2021 09:28:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) | screen_view
```

Device info

[Device Information img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BS2h.png)

Comment: Check if you are using "d.e.c.a.c" class in your project, check android directory for it. Or may be issue with some flutter library.