# My Flutter App is Crashing on several devices after launching on playstore (SQLiteConnection.java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, sqlite

I have launched an app on play store but it is crashing on several devices & I am not able test my app on every devices. i have crashlytics report

**Crashlytics Report**

Stack Trace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (23.0.1).
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:19)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run(-.java:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:962)
```

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5 SQLITE_BUSY)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:14)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

```
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5 SQLITE_BUSY)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:578)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:323)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:298)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:553)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteDatabase.java:517)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction(SQLitePersistence.java:17)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.startMutationQueue(LocalStore.java:9)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.start(LocalStore.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ComponentProvider.initialize(ComponentProvider.java:41)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(FirestoreClient.java:65)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0(FirestoreClient.java:10)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0$FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.-$$Lambda$FirestoreClient$Eq-cAcb1C1mM4tyiJsLJXZ13tyU.run(-.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$Y9GO7zO2DX6MzQJ5TbKtKW_NzO0.call(-.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Device Information

```
Brand:OPPO
Model:
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 3.28 GB
Disk free: 95.39 GB
Date: 26-07-2021
```

Operating System

```
Version:9
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted:No
```

Other devices with same issue

```
Oppo: F17 Pro,CPH1853
Realme: 5i,c12,8pro
vivo: 1920,1803
```

Comment: hi, were you able to find the cause for this crash? I am seeing lots of crashes on android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Flutter App is Crashing on several devices after launching on playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524717/my-flutter-app-is-crashing-on-several-devices-after-launching-on-playstore)

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is that an sqlite query is being executed on an sqlite connection that is already processing a query based on the fact that it  is executing side a threaded background worker. it is possible that the system sqlite on this system may be compiled differently such as being in single threaded mode

the cause of this looks to be the firebase library and how it operates and if this is a systems issue (android on the oppo and the provided sqlite) then you may have to detect how it was compiled or bundle a verison of sqlite to work around this

it should be possible to dump the compile options of sqlite via an sql conenction and compare this to a knwn